# Jacobi identity of the anti-bracket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, poisson-brackets, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

I'm currently reading a volume 2 of Weinberg's QFT, and am puzzled by the Jacobi identities of the [anti-bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerstenhaber_algebra).

The anti-bracket is defined using the anti-field $\chi^n$ and $\chi_n^{‡}$ as follows
$$(F, G)\equiv \frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi^n}\frac{\delta_L G}{\delta\chi_n^‡}-\frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi_n^{‡}}\frac{\delta_L G}{\delta\chi^n} \tag{1}$$
where one of $\chi_n$ and $\chi_n^‡$ is Grassmann and the other is a boson-like field that is not Grassmann.

In this case, the anti-bracket satisfies the following Jacobi identity

$$(-1)^{(1+|F|)(1+|H|)}(F, (G, H))+(-1)^{(1+|G|)(1+|F|)}(G, (H, F))+(-1)^{(1+|H|)(1+|G|)}(H, (F, G))=0.\tag{2}$$
For simplicity, I tried to show this for $n=1$, where there is only one type of antifield. I thought I would simply move my hand, but for example, the term $(F, (G, H))$ is expanded as
$$
\begin{split}
(F,(G,H))&= \frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi}\frac{\delta_L (G,H)}{\delta\chi^‡}-\frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi^{‡}}\frac{\delta_L (G,H)}{\delta\chi}\\
&= \frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi}\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\chi^‡}\Big(\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi}\frac{\delta_L H}{\delta\chi^‡}-\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi^{‡}}\frac{\delta_L H}{\delta\chi}\Big)-\frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi^{‡}}\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\chi} \Big(\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi}\frac{\delta_L H}{\delta\chi^‡}-\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi^{‡}}\frac{\delta_L H}{\delta\chi}\Big)\\
&= \frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi}\Big(\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\chi^‡}\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi}\Big)\frac{\delta_L H}{\delta\chi^‡}+(-1)^{|\chi^‡||G|} \frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi}\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi}\Big(\frac{\delta_L }{\delta\chi^‡}\frac{\delta_LH}{\delta\chi^‡}\Big)\\
&\ \ -\frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi}\Big(\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\chi^‡}\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi^‡}\Big)\frac{\delta_L H}{\delta\chi}-(-1)^{|\chi^‡||G|} \frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi}\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi^‡}\Big(\frac{\delta_L }{\delta\chi^‡}\frac{\delta_LH}{\delta\chi}\Big)\\
&\ \  -\frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi^‡}\Big(\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\chi}\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi}\Big)\frac{\delta_L H}{\delta\chi^‡}-(-1)^{|\chi||G|} \frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi^‡}\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi}\Big(\frac{\delta_L }{\delta\chi}\frac{\delta_LH}{\delta\chi^‡}\Big)\\
&\ \ +\frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi^‡}\Big(\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\chi}\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi^‡}\Big)\frac{\delta_L H}{\delta\chi}+(-1)^{|\chi||G|} \frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \chi^‡}\frac{\delta_R G}{\delta \chi^‡}\Big(\frac{\delta_L }{\delta\chi}\frac{\delta_LH}{\delta\chi}\Big),\\
\end{split}\tag{3}$$
and here I am left with the information about the grassmann parity of the antifield $|\chi|$. Because this factor is left until the end of the calculation, I can’t show the Jacobi identity.

Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Hint: The 4th and 6th term on the RHS of eq. (3) in v4 have wrong signs.

Comment: I think the sign in equation (3) is probably correct, but in the end I found out that it was due to a simple miscalculation in swapping the terms. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Show that eq. (1) simplifies to
   $$(B, B)~=~ 2\frac{\delta_R B}{\delta \chi^n}\frac{\delta_L B}{\delta\chi_n^{\ddagger}}~=~-2\frac{\delta_R B}{\delta \chi_n^{\ddagger}}\frac{\delta_L B}{\delta\chi^n} \tag{i}$$ for the same
   Grassmann-even function $B$.
2. Show the Jacobi identity
   $$ (B,(B, B))~=~\ldots~=~\text{only 4 terms}~=~\ldots~=~0. \tag{ii}$$
3. Insert
   $$ B=\alpha F+ \beta G + \gamma H \tag{iii}$$
   into the Jacobi identity (ii), where $\alpha$, $\beta$ & $\gamma$ are super number parameters of the same Grassmann-parity as $F$, $G$ & $H$, respectively.
4. Finally use the graded bi-linarity and the graded symmetry property of the antibracket. The terms proportional the parameter monomial $\alpha\beta\gamma$ yields the sought-for Jacobi identity for $F$, $G$ & $H$.